# Having trouble with this bootstrap header in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

i have bootstrap installed into my app but this video header that i am using is not showing correctly on my local server. so i guess the dependency is not working on my end.

CodePen https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-8w7yv

I have downloaded bootstrap and it is showing in node modules it is working in sandbox but not on my server
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

```
export default class Intro extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header>
        <div className="overlay"></div>
        <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
          <source src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Mt_Baker.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>>
        </video>
        <div className="container h-100">
          <div className="d-flex h-100 text-center align-items-center">
            <div className="w-100 text-white">
              <h1 className="display-3">Video Header</h1>
              <p className="lead mb-0">With HTML5 Video and Bootstrap 4</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>      
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems I didn't understand your question properly. But with your Code Pen, I replaced its content with your source code of video and see it works. Please check picture below

[image]